# ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, interface

I'm looking online for a practical example on how the `StreamingContext` parameter for this interface would be used, but I'm not finding anything.  Even the documentation on the [MS Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.aspx) only mentions it in passing.  Can someone give a demonstration of how and when this would be used?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is used internaly in BCL, you do not actually need this StreamingContext, because implementation is hidden. You can disassemble BCL assemblies to look into StreamingContext (ildsam mscorlib.dll)

Example of usage of StreamingContext (it is used as a constructor parameter):

```
  .method assembly hidebysig instance void 
          CompleteSerialization(object serializedObject,
                                class System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
                                valuetype System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) cil managed
  {
    .custom instance void System.Security.SecurityCriticalAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
    // Размер кода:       88 (0x58)
    .maxstack  4
    .locals init (class System.EventHandler`1<class System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationEventArgs> V_0,
             class System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationEventArgs V_1)
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  ldnull
    IL_0002:  stfld      class System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<object> System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager::m_serializedStates
    IL_0007:  ldarg.0
    IL_0008:  ldfld      class System.EventHandler`1<class System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationEventArgs> System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager::SerializeObjectState
    IL_000d:  stloc.0
    IL_000e:  ldloc.0
    IL_000f:  brfalse.s  IL_0057

    IL_0011:  ldarg.3
    IL_0012:  newobj     instance void System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationEventArgs::.ctor(valuetype System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)
    IL_0017:  stloc.1
    IL_0018:  ldloc.0
    IL_0019:  ldarg.1
    IL_001a:  ldloc.1
    IL_001b:  callvirt   instance void class System.EventHandler`1<class System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationEventArgs>::Invoke(object,
                                                                                                                                          !0)
    IL_0020:  ldarg.0
    IL_0021:  ldloc.1
    IL_0022:  callvirt   instance class System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<object> System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationEventArgs::get_SerializedStates()
    IL_0027:  stfld      class System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<object> System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager::m_serializedStates
    IL_002c:  ldarg.2
    IL_002d:  ldstr      "CLR_SafeSerializationManager_RealType"
    IL_0032:  ldarg.1
    IL_0033:  callvirt   instance class System.Type System.Object::GetType()
    IL_0038:  ldtoken    System.RuntimeType
    IL_003d:  call       class System.Type System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    IL_0042:  callvirt   instance void System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo::AddValue(string,
                                                                                                object,
                                                                                                class System.Type)
    IL_0047:  ldarg.2
    IL_0048:  ldtoken    System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager
    IL_004d:  call       class System.Type System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
    IL_0052:  callvirt   instance void System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo::SetType(class System.Type)
    IL_0057:  ret
  } // end of method SafeSerializationManager::CompleteSerialization
```

Comment: Hmm.. then why is it part of the public interface?